# Missing required view with ID. What is my fault?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to `android studio`. When using `binding` in `recyclerview adapter`, I got the following error : Missing required view with ID

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.co_investorux_ui, PID: 18057
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: com.example.co_investorux_ui:id/app_name
        at com.example.co_investorux_ui.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.bind(ActivityMainBinding.java:151)
        at com.example.co_investorux_ui.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.kt:205)
        at com.example.co_investorux_ui.RecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.kt:183)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7295)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6416)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.onLayout(SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:863)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:779)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2590)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

When I didn't use `binding`, it worked fine with no errors.

Code without `binding`

```
    //recyclerview adapter
    class RecyclerViewAdapter(
        val itemList: ArrayList<CoinList>,
        val inflater: LayoutInflater
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {
        private var searchList: ArrayList<CoinList>? = null

        inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val name: TextView
            val count: TextView

            init {
                name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coin_name)
                count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coin_count)
            }
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.name.setText(itemList.get(position).name)
            holder.count.setText(itemList.get(position).count)
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            }
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return itemList.size
        }

    }
```

Code using `binding`

```
// recyclerview adapter
class RecyclerViewAdapter(
    val itemList: ArrayList<MainActivity.CoinList>,
    val inflater: LayoutInflater
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    private var searchList: ArrayList<MainActivity.CoinList>? = null

    class ViewHolder(val binding: ActivityMainBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val name: TextView
        val count: TextView

        init {
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coin_name)
            count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coin_count)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(ActivityMainBinding.bind(view))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.name.setText(itemList.get(position).name)
        holder.count.setText(itemList.get(position).count)
        val slidePanel = holder.binding.mainFrame

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val state = slidePanel.panelState
            // Open slidePanel when it closed.
            if (state == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED) {
                slidePanel.panelState = SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED
            }
            // Close slidePanel when it open
            else if (state == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED) {
                slidePanel.panelState = SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

}
```

`xml` code

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:umanoDragView="@id/slide_layout"
    app:umanoPanelHeight="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="430dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search_view" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/slide_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="430dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"></androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>


</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

I am implementing a function that `sildinguppanellayout` is called when the `itemview` of the `recyclerview` is clicked, but I can't solve the error.

Could you please let me know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`ActivityMainBinding` will only bind views created from `activity_main.xml` (note the naming). To bind views created from `item_view.xml`, you need to use `ItemViewBinding.bind(view)`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But I have already used `ItemViewBinding`. To call `slidinguppanellayout`, I need to get the state of `mainFrame`, and the `mainFrame` is created in `activity_main.xml`. Is there any solution in this case?

Comment: `val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)`

`return ViewHolder(ActivityMainBinding.bind(view))`

this portion

Comment: Make sure you're using binding classes that match the layout used to create the view. Also, you're using item Id along with binding, that's not the proper use of binding.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Thanks to you, I realized that my problem was not only due to `binding`. Whether using `binding` or `findviewbyid`, I need to reference two `xmls(activity_main, item_view)` in the `recyclerview adapter`. `activity_main` is needed to get the state of `mainFrame`. As you can see from the `code without binding`, I am only referencing `item_view`. Is there any way to reference `activity_main` and `item_view` at the same time in `recyclerview adapter`? If there is a way, I think I can solve the problem. I'm not good enough, but thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not familiar with that library, does the library provide any callback when the state is changed? Or do you have to check manually every time? Either way, the more efficient approach would be to provide the Slidepanel as a parameter for the adapter, then check state through that. Binding and rebinding views everytime will lead to chaos.

Comment: Bind Slidepanel from activity, provide Slidepanel object to the adapter.